# how to apply laravel unique validation for array with ignore current id from an array?

Tags: laravel

I have array from client side like below

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        name:'apple',
        ...,
        ...
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'mango',
        ...,
        ...
    },
    {
        new:true,
        name : 'stawberry'
    }
]
```

as you see in third object i have key new:"true" which means this object is about to insert not update and above 2 objects are about to update as they have id as well.

now i have to apply back end validation with ignore function of laravel to ignore for update.

```
$rules = [
    '*.name'=>[
        'required',
        Rule::unique('inventories', 'name')->ignore(?),
        'distinct'
    ],
];
```

Comment: forget about conventional rules, you're not using conventional update/insert. You can manage to do it with custom rules and looping elements.

Comment: @N69S yes i thought may be we have optimal solution from laravel

Comment: what would be optimal is that you seperate the to be updates entries and to be inserted entries, each in its own array. So you can validate the fields in seperate rules.